# What is the message behind Where the Wild Things Are?

Tags: analysis, where-the-wild-things-are

What really is the message behind the movie, [Where The Wild Things Are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are_%28film%29)?

I've seen the movie year ago, and still couldn't figure it out.

Comment: It's based on the children's book. So if you google the children's book I'm sure Maurice Sendak has an explanation somewhere. WikiPedia talks about the book here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Where_the_Wild_Things_Are

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't let your emotions get the best of you.

Each wild thing represented a (bad) part of the kid. He had to give it up to be with his family.